# what would my command arguments be for my timer

Tags: java, timer, command-line-arguments

So, I've been trying to figure out how this timer works, and now that I finally got it to compile with no errors, I can't seem to get it to run properly, I'm assuming because I'm not giving it the proper cmd ln args but I don't know what args to provide. the code is as follows:

```
import java.time.*;

public class Clock {
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime stopTime;
    private Duration duration;
    private int hours, minutes, seconds;

    // no argument constructor that initializes the startTime to the current time
    public Clock() {
        startTime = LocalTime.now();
    }
    public Clock(LocalTime start, LocalTime stop) {
        startTime = start;
        stopTime = stop;
    }


    //public Clock(start, stop) {

    //}

    // resets the startTime to the given time
    public void start(int h, int m, int s) {
        hours = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minutes = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        seconds = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
        startTime = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    //a stop() method that sets the endTime to the given time
    public void stop(int h, int m, int s) {
        hours = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minutes = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        seconds = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
        stopTime = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    //a getElapsedTime() method that returns the elapsed time in seconds
    public Duration getElapsedTime() {
        System.out.println("Difference is " + Duration.between(stopTime, startTime).toNanos()/1_000_000_000.0 + " Seconds.");
        duration = Duration.between(stopTime, startTime);
        return duration;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       LocalTime argOne;
       LocalTime argTwo;
       argOne = LocalTime.parse(args[0]);
       argTwo = LocalTime.parse(args[1]);
       Clock clockOne = new Clock(argOne, argTwo);
       clockOne.getElapsedTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what it 's supposed to be, I somehow doubt you wrote this code yourself ... What have you tried passing as arguments?

Comment: I never said I wrote it myself, I just want to figure out how to make it work to help me better understand everything thats happening here.I've tried typing "java Clock *int* *int*" "java Clock *int*" and even "java Clock *string* and it gives me an exception in main java.time.etc ParseException: *int* could not be parsed in index *#index*

Comment: What are the actual values you are passing it, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: how on earth do you expect "int" to be parsed to a LocalTime ??
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

Comment: Perhaps read the Javadoc for [`LocalTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), which gives example inputs.

Comment: holy crap! i figured it out!!! nvm thank you guys sorry for sounding douchey I appreciate all the comments!

Comment: @3monkeys1gorilla, if you figured it out, you should probably add the solution to help anyone in future with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

after successful compile, command line args should be in this format, (to include calling the java class) so mine would look like:

java Clock 03:14:43 03:17:00 || java Clock 03:14 03:17

expected output:Elapsed time in seconds: 180